# Mapping Java 8 Stream to elements' method reference

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Let's say I have an interface like this:

```
public interface Service {  
    List<Result> getResults();  
    // some other methods  
}
```

I have a `List` of implementations of that interface in `List<Service> services`.

How do I transform that `List` into a `List` of method references to the `getResults` method (or even better: a `List` of `Supplier<List<Result>>`) dynamically?

I was looking for something akin to

```
List<Supplier<List<Result>>> = services.stream()
    .map(s -> s::getResults)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: `.map(Service::getResults)`? Although maybe you want to flatmap that. What do you mean by *list of method references*?

Comment: That would map to stream of `Result`. I'm interested in stream of `Supplier<List<Result>>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems the compiler needs some help with type inference.

```
List<Supplier<List<Result>>> list = 
    services.stream()
            .map(s -> (Supplier<List<Result>>)(() -> s.getResults()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Here's a working example which replaces your `Service` interface with `StringBuilder` and your `Result` with `String`. I'm using `Arrays.asList(s.toString().split(" "))` to produce a `List<String>` from each `StringBuilder`.

```
List<StringBuilder> services = new ArrayList<>();
services.add (new StringBuilder());
services.add (new StringBuilder());
services.get (0).append ("one two three");
services.get (1).append ("four five six");
List<Supplier<List<String>>> list = 
services.stream()
        .map(s -> (Supplier<List<String>>) (() -> Arrays.asList(s.toString().split(" "))))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println (list.get (0).get ());
System.out.println (list.get (1).get ());
```

Output :

```
[one, two, three]
[four, five, six]
```

Comment: Great! Apparently, lambda just needs a cast to `Supplier` and I'm all set. Thx.

Comment: @cbaby Yes, I just found that out when I tried to run this code (or actually, similar code, since I didn't have your `Supplier` and `Result`).

Comment: This can also be done before the `map` stage like: `services.stream().<Supplier<List<String>>>map(...)`

Comment: "You can't include a method reference inside a lambda expression" -- wrong statement.

Comment: Why do you think you can’t include a method reference inside a lambda expression? There is no difference between `.map(s -> (Supplier<List<Result>>)(() -> s.getResults()))` and `.map(s -> (Supplier<List<Result>>)s::getResults)`.

Answer (score 3):

Method references have no particular type (they can be mapped to various functional interfaces, for example `Supplier` or `Callable`), so you have to add a hint to the compiler, when the type can’t be inferred. Casting is one possibility, but I prefer explicit generic argument:

```
List<Supplier<List<Result>>> list = services.stream()
    .<Supplier<List<Result>>>map(s -> s::getResults)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In general there's no restriction on using method references inside lambda expressions.